# How do I send the email object to a function?

Tags: vba, outlook

If have a function that loops through a selection of emails, an email is an object not a lose variable ([Passing variable from Form to Module in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214072/passing-variable-from-form-to-module-in-vba)):

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    moveMail(TextBox1.Value, objItem)
Next
End Sub
```

based on - lets say - the subject I want to do something with that email. That means that I will have to move the mail object to a function. But if do like I did it now I get an error.

```
compiling error    
synstaxt error
```

Comment: Show the moveMail() function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variable from Form to Module in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214072/passing-variable-from-form-to-module-in-vba)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible, you just need to be more careful declaring your variables.

```
Sub schaap()
For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Dim mailbericht As Object
    Set mailbericht = objItem
    Call cavia(mailbericht)
Next
End Sub

Function cavia(mailbericht As Object)
    MsgBox mailbericht.Subject
End Function
```