# Assigning a variable directly from a userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add some code to have a userform pop up which allows the end user to input their login/password for s specific website. This code [Passing variable from Form to Module in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214072/passing-variable-from-form-to-module-in-vba) got me closer to my goal but I am not sure how to make it work the way I need to. Here is the code for my userform.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UPass = UserForm1.UserID
Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UID = UserForm1.WavePassword
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

And I am using the below in the code to log into the website.

```
    Public Sub Connect_To_Wave()
    Dim Dasboard As Worksheet
        Set Dashboard = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")
    Dim UID As String
        UID = driver.findElementByName("PASSWORD").SendKeys UID
    Dim UPass As String
        UPass = driver.findElementByName("PASSWORD").SendKeys Upass




Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
my_url = "url of website - not a variable"

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate my_url
    .Top = 100
    .Left = 530
    .Height = 700
    .Width = 400

Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End With

ie.Document.getElementById("txtLoginUsername").Value = ""
ie.Document.getElementById("txtLoginPassword").Value = ""
ie.Document.getElementById("txtLoginUsername").Value = UID
ie.Document.getElementById("txtLoginPassword").Value = UPass
ie.Document.getElementById("btnLogin").Click

Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
End Sub
```

The issue I am running into is that I get an error of "expected end of statement" on the uid/upass variables. How do I correctly get the userform to pass the input directly into the variable so the variable can be used to log into the website? I am completely open to change the method if there is a better way as well.

Comment: I haven't even gotten to the point of running either set of code. As I finished typing the UID = / UPass = lines they both turned red and flagged the error.

Comment: Procedure `CommandButton1_Click` is defined twice. That can't compile. Also `Connect_To_Wave()` should be `ConnectToWave(ByVal uid As String, ByVal pwd As String)` - you're not showing where the form is instanciated, but it assigning global variables and unloading the global/default instance of the form isn't a sign of solid code.

Comment: I made those changes as suggested. I am not sure how to test it from here. I hit F8 to run the userform and that is running as expected I think but I am not sure how to test the login code at the same time. When I try to F8 the login code now it just dings but does not provide an error message.

Comment: @TonyP if the code is now working, then you can submit it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: @MacroMan I am not sure if it is working. For some reason it won't let me run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't possibly compile:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UPass = UserForm1.UserID
Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UID = UserForm1.WavePassword
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

A procedure cannot exist twice. Rename your button `OkButton`, add some `CancelButton` and rewrite your form's code-behind as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Private cancelling As Boolean

Public Property Get UID() As String
    UID = UserID.Text
End Property

Public Property Get PWD() As String
    PWD = WavePassword.Text
End Property

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = cancelling
End Property

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    cancelling = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        cancelling = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

Notice `OkButton`, `CancelButton` and the `QueryClose` handler only ever **Hide** the form, so the calling code can still read the `IsCancelled`, `UID` and `PWD` property values.

That calling code could do this - assuming the UserForm is renamed to `LoginPrompt`:

```
Public Sub DownloadStuff()
    With New LoginPrompt
        .Show vbModal
        If .IsCancelled Then Exit Sub
        ConnectToWave .UID, .PWD
    End With
End Sub
```

And last, the `ConnectToWave` procedure, taking the user's input:

```
Private Sub ConnectToWave(ByVal userID As String, ByVal password As String)
    ' there, you got your values from the form - now use them!
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a basic question but where would I put the Public Sub Downloadstuff() in the module with the ConnecttoWave or with the userform?

Comment: That would be in a standard module, and could be exposed as a macro attached to a button on the worksheet, for example - I'd put it alongside the `ConnectToWave` procedure.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW I added an answer to the question you linked.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what `driver` is but this statement is wrong

`UID = driver.findElementByName("PASSWORD").SendKeys UID`  as `Sendkeys` is a method so when trying to assign the return value you need to use brackets.

Try this :

`UID = driver.findElementByName("PASSWORD").SendKeys(UID)`

Comment: driver was some object used in the linked post/ findElementByName is a method that is part of the ArcObjects library. Given that the OP has no idea how to declare global variables, I highly doubt he is using ArcObjects.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
Dim UID As String
    UID = driver.findElementByName("PASSWORD").SendKeys UID
Dim UPass As String
    UPass = driver.findElementByName("PASSWORD").SendKeys Upass
```

Should be:

```
Dim UID As String
    UID = driver.findElementByName("PASSWORD").SendKeys(UID)
Dim UPass As String
    UPass = driver.findElementByName("PASSWORD").SendKeys(Upass)
```

---

If you are calling a function that isn't assigning anything back to a value then you don't need to use parentheses, but if it's assigning something to a variable then you need to use the above syntax instead.

*Where `Foo()` is a function and `Bar` is a variable*

```
'// Not assigning a value
Foo Bar

'// Assigning a value
someVar = Foo(Bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you want, you have to create a global variable at the top of your module. I doubt you are using ArcObjects so scrap the whole `driver.findElementByName` stuff. Besides, you already set the value of the username and password fields correctly (this bit: `ie.Document.getElementById("txtLoginUsername").Value = UID`) so there's no need for any `SendKeys` method.

What you need is something like this at the very top of your code module:

```
Option Explicit
Public UID as String
Public UPass as String
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I do have the publics at the top.

Comment: @Tim the error message is being caused by incorrect syntax, not variable scope.