# Treat Userform as a Function

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have created a VBA UserForm which is essentially a glorified input box

Just like an input box can be employed like this

```
Dim returnVal As String
returnVal = InputBox("Write some string")
```

I would like my userform to run like this

```
Dim returnVal As customClass
Set returnVal = MyUserForm([some arguments])
```

ie. the `MyUserForm()` code passes some arguments to the userform, and when the userform is closed, it gets some arguments back (in the form of a custom class rather than a plain string)

**What's the best way of structuring my userform to allow this functionality?**

---

Currently, I'm just declaring some variables and the custom class publicly. I'm catching command button clicks and `Query_close()` events to hide the form, then I read the outputVal and close the form completely. I don't like this because I'd like my form to be totally self contained, and I think the capturing of events is messy.

In simplified code (read/return a string):

```
Function myUf(inVal As String) As String
Dim frm As New frmTest
frm.inputval = inVal
frm.Init 'sets caption. We cannot rely on userform initialize as this runs before inputval is set
         'We could pass a variable here to save writing to the public variable
frm.Show
myUf = frm.outputVal
Set frm = Nothing
End Function
```

And in my Userform called `frmTest` with a textbox called `tb1`

```
Public inputval As String
Public outputVal As String

Public Sub Init()
Me.Caption = inputval 'setting caption, but could pass this anywhere
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
If CloseMode <> 1 Then Cancel = 1
outputVal = tb1 'reading value from textbox, but could return anything here
Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a way to initiate the UserForm from a ClassObject. Then, you can use a [simple factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) to create the UserForm exactly the way you want.

---

In general, I have copied a bit of the code of [Mat's Mug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mats-mug) somewhere in StackOverflow and I wrote an article about the User Forms. If you take a look here (http://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-the-perfect-userform-in-vba/) you will find a way to initialize the form with `Public Sub ShowMainForm()` It's possible to add a parameter to the ShowMainForm, then pass it to the initializer of the class.

In general, take the code from the article, make sure it works, and change the `ShowMainForm` initializer to the following:

```
Public Sub ShowMainForm(strText As String, strText2 As String)

    If (objPresenter Is Nothing) Then
        Set objPresenter = New clsSummaryPresenter
    End If

    objPresenter.Show
    Call objPresenter.ChangeLabelAndCaption(strText, strText2)

End Sub
```

Then, if you call like this in the immediate window:

```
call ShowMainForm("Just","testing")
```

You will get this:

[image]

Which is quite what you need. :)

Comment: appreciated your article+. It could be of some interest to have a look at my recently posted question how to "destroy a *modeless* userform instance properly", as I referred to Mat's Mug's MVP concept, too  (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357708/vba-destroy-a-modeless-userform-instance-properly).

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is:

Create a Function in witch you combine your arguments to a string like:

```
strOpenArg = "param1:=value1;param2:=value2;"
```

than open the form with the OpenArgs

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "UserForm", acNormal, , , , acDialog, strOpenArgs
```

get your value and close the Form

```
Value= Form_UserForm.Value

DoCmd.Close acForm, "UserForm", acSaveNo
```

in the UserForm set Form_open. Here you can get your parameters.you can devide this by string splitting.
Set also an OK Button, where you make the form just invisible and set the return value

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
     Dim strParameter as String
     strParameter = Me.OpenArgs 'Here are your parmeters
End Sub

Private Sub ok_Click()
    m_Value = "Your ReturnValue"
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub

Private m_Value As String
Public Property Get Value() As String
    Value = m_msgBoxResult
End Property
```

Comment: This is code for an MSAccess form, not code for a VBA Userform.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to one-liner the code like you want to, unfortunately. If all your userform code is self-contained then the only way for it to pass values out is to change the values of public variables. [Mat's Mug's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38382104/8205970) is the layout I usually use when trying to simulate functions like 'InputBox' but you still can't get it in one line without writing a separate function. Using userform properties allows you to contain more of your code within the form itself.