# VBA - destroy a modeless UserForm instance properly

Tags: vba, excel, userform

**Intro:**

I am aware that - showing UserForms - it's best practice to

- handle `QueryClose` within the userform code (`If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu ...`)
- doing no `Unload Me` therein, just a timid `Me.Hide` instruction 
  (after preventing [x]-itting and eventual self-destruction via `Cancel = True` )
- setting a related variable/[property] within the [class] code (e.g. `.IsCancelled=True`)
- in order to be able to have the UF unloaded by the *calling code*.

**Useful link**

An outstanding overview *"UserForm1.Show?"* can be found at https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/
as well as in numerous examplary SO answers (thx to Mathieu Guindon aka *Mat's Mug* and RubberDuck).

**Further selection** (►*edit as of 5/1 2019*)

- [Disadvantages in putting code into userforms instead of modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288496/are-there-disadvantages-in-putting-code-into-userforms-instead-of-modules/47291028?r=SearchResults&s=1|22.6047#47291028)
- [Passing variable from form to module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214072/passing-variable-from-form-to-module-in-vba/38382104#38382104)
- [Apply logic for userform dialog (Rubberduck)](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/05/08/apply-logic-for-userform-dialog/)
- [The perfect userform (Vitosh academy)](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-the-perfect-userform-in-vba/)

---

**1) Working examples for modal UserForms**

As far as I understood - and I do try to learn -, the following code should be okay for **modal** UF's:

**Case 1a)** .. with a **local variable** for the UF instance, as often seen:

```
Public Sub ShowFormA
  Dim ufA As UserForm1
  Set ufA = New UserForm1
' show userform 
  ufA.Show          ' equivalent to: ufA.Show vbModal

' handle data after user okay
  If Not ufA.IsCancelled Then
      '  do something ...
  End If

' >> object reference destroyed expressly (as seen in some examples)
  unload ufA
End Sub
```

**Case 1b)** .. without a local variable, but using a `With New` codeblock:

```
' ----------------------------------------------------------
' >> no need to destruct object reference expressly,
'    as it will be destroyed whenever exiting the with block
' ----------------------------------------------------------
  With New UserForm1
      .Show         ' equivalent to: ufA.Show vbModal

    ' handle data after user okay
      If Not .IsCancelled Then
      '  do something ...
      End If
  End With
```

---

**2) Problem**

Problems arise using a **MODELESS** UserForm instance.

Okay, the with block method (cf. 1b) should be sufficient to destroy any object reference after x-iting it:

```
  With New UserForm1
      .Show vbModeless  ' << show modeless uf
  End With
```

If I try, however to

- a) get information about a possible user cancelling as well as
- b) to `Unload` a form if baptized using a local variable (e.g. "ufA") after the `Show` instruction,

all code lines will be executed at once for precisely the reason that the form is MODELESS:

- code shows the form, the next moment ..
- code finds no user cancelling, as there was no time for any user action, the next moment ..
- [code unloads the form if using a local variable for the userform]

---

**3) Question**

How can I handle a) correctly reported UserForm cancels by the calling code of a MODELESS form as well as b) a (necessary?) unloading if using a local variable?

Comment: @Mat's Mug ad) edit: of course there has to be a `If Not` **Ufa**`.IsCancelled` in 1a) - one should keep away from copying an apparently similar code some lines below (cf. 1b) :-). Nevertheless I hope having contributed a helpful question at least for learning programmers.

Comment: @Mat's Mug, I appreciate your clearing up some background by your comment, thus confirming me in my resolve to explore the OOP capacities of VBA and to try MVP solutions.
This even more as (unexplained) downvoting is pretty unfair if it results from differing philosophies only. BTW, *rubber* can be a very solid material :-;

Comment: I'd even say [SOLID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Indeed, I've been focusing quite a lot on modal forms - because that's what's most commonly used. Thanks for the feedback on that article!

The principles are the same for non-modal forms though: simply expand on the *Model-View-Presenter* pattern roughly outlined in the linked article and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47291028/1188513).

The difference is that a non-modal form needs a paradigm shift: you're no longer responding to a preset sequence of events - rather, you need to respond to some asynchronous *events* that may happen at any given time, or not.

- When handling a modal form, there's a "before showing" and then an "after hiding" that runs immediately after the form is hidden. You can handle anything that happens "while showing" using events.
- When handling a non-modal form, there's a "before showing", and then "while showing" and "after showing" *both* need to be handled through events.

Make your presenter class module responsible for holding the `UserForm` instance, at module-level and `WithEvents`:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents myModelessForm As UserForm1
```

The presenter's `Show` method will `Set` the form instance and display it:

```
Public Sub Show()
    'If Not myModelessForm Is Nothing Then
    '    myModelessForm.Visible = True 'just to ensure visibility & honor the .Show call
    '    Exit Sub
    'End If
    Set myModelessForm = New UserForm1
    '...
    myModelessForm.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

You **don't** want the form instance to be local to the procedure here, so a local variable **or** a `With` block can't work: the object will be out of scope before you mean it to. That's why you store the instance in a private field, at module level: now the form lives as long as the presenter instance does.

Now, you need to make the form "talk" to the presenter - the easiest way is to expose events in the `UserForm1` code-behind - for example if we want the user to confirm cancellation, we'll add a `ByRef` parameter to the event, so the handler in the presenter can pass the information back to the event source (i.e. back to the form code):

```
Option Explicit
'...private fields, model, etc...
Public Event FormConfirmed()
Public Event FormCancelled(ByRef Cancel as Boolean)

'returns True if cancellation was cancelled by handler
Private Function OnCancel() As Boolean
    Dim cancelCancellation As Boolean
    RaiseEvent FormCancelled(cancelCancellation)
    If Not cancelCancellation Then Me.Hide
    OnCancel = cancelCancellation
End Function

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    OnCancel
End Sub

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
    RaiseEvent FormConfirmed
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = Not OnCancel
    End If
End Sub
```

Now the presenter can handle that `FormCancelled` event:

```
Private Sub myModelessForm_FormCancelled(ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
    'setting Cancel to True will leave the form open
    Cancel = MsgBox("Cancel this operation?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation) = vbNo
    If Not Cancel Then
        ' modeless form was cancelled and is now hidden.
        ' ...
        Set myModelessForm = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub myModelessForm_FormConfirmed()
    'form was okayed and is now hidden.
    '...
    Set myModelessForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

A non-modal form wouldn't *typically* have "ok" and "cancel" buttons though. Rather, you'd have a number of functionalities exposed, for example one that brings up some modal dialog `UserForm2` that does something else - again, you just expose an event for it, and handle it in the presenter:

```
Public Event ShowGizmo()

Private Sub ShowGizmoButton_Click()
    RaiseEvent ShowGizmo
End Sub
```

And the presenter goes:

```
Private Sub myModelessForm_ShowGizmo()
    With New GizmoPresenter
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that the modal `UserForm2` is a concern of a separate presenter class.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful and detailed descriptions, appreciate it.

Comment: This is a  very informative answer and great piece of knowledge. And its simply an OVERKILL. If you need to create/deploy this type of solution in VBA project then you are most certainly not using the best tool for your work.  VBA can do alot of things. But just because it could that doesn't mean you should.  Trying to implement MVVM or MVC in VBA. Possible? Yes, as very rightly showed by @Mat'sMug. But if you are in need of MVC implementation and still stuck with Excel-VBA due to any reason, reconsider your specs and re-analyse. Again, this answer is very good.

Comment: When I try this in Word, it seems as though Events don't fire. But when I show the form as `vbModal` all events fire and get handled. Is there a way to get a modeless form to raise events in Word?

Comment: @xidgel strange, the default for the optional parameter of MSForms.UserForm.Show is `vbModal`... You can't declare a local form that you show modeless in the same procedure scope - execution won't be blocked at `.Show` and the form will pretty much instantly fall out of scope - you need to hold that object reference at module level so that the object remains programmatically accessible.

Comment: I'd make the form object a private instance field of the presenter class, and have an instance of the presenter live at module-level in a standard module.

Answer (score 3):

I typically tie the lifetime of a modeless userform instance to the workbook's by putting code along those lines behind ThisWorkbook:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_MyForm As UserForm1

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not m_MyForm Is Nothing Then
        Unload m_MyForm
        Set m_MyForm = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Friend Property Get MyForm() As UserForm1
    If m_MyForm Is Nothing Then
        Set m_MyForm = New UserForm1
    End If

    Set MyForm = m_MyForm
End Property
```

You can then refer to the modeless code throughout your code using e.g.

```
ThisWorkbook.MyForm.Show vbModeless
```

etc.

Comment: Another working method with the possible disadvantage of late unloading.

Comment: I would like to replicate your solution but this doesn't seem to work for me. I am not able to access the  `ThisWoorkBook.MyForm` property.

Comment: Is your workbook object's name indeed "ThisWorkbook"? This name can be changed, from the VBA editor, in the workbook's properties list, under the (Name) property. If, for example, the workbook's (Name) is MyWorkbook, you'd invoke MyWorkbook.MyForm.Show. Also, double check that you've used the Friend access level; Private won't work. If it still doesn't work, tell me more about the context from which you're trying to access the property.

Answer (score 3):

For modeless forms, Use DoEvents coupled with custom userform property.

---

```
Sub test()

    Dim frm As New UserForm1

    frm.Show vbModeless

    Do
        DoEvents
        If frm.Cancelled Then
            Unload frm
        Exit Do
    End If
    Loop Until False

    MsgBox "You closed the modeless form."

    '/ Using With
    With New UserForm1
        .Show vbModeless
        Do
            DoEvents
            If .Cancelled Then Exit Do
        Loop Until False
    End With

    MsgBox "You closed the modeless form (with)"

End Sub
```

'/ User Form

```
Private m_bCancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
    Cancelled = m_bCancelled
End Property

Public Property Let Cancelled(ByVal bNewValue As Boolean)
    m_bCancelled = bNewValue
End Property
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Me.Cancelled = True
    Cancel = 1
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Think this to be an elegant method to let the calling code the responsibility to destroy/unload the form.

Comment: Adding a while loop to test if a form is closed might as well be doing a modal form.  You are halting execution until a form is closed.