# How do I pass a range object to a property in VBA?

Tags: excel, userform, vba

though searched thoroughly I don't get a range passed into a userform via property. I get the error object required. The code is inside the userform, the parameter prange is global. Any help would be appreciated much. Thanks.

```
Public Property Get MyRng() As Range

Set MyRng = r1

End Property

Public Property Set MyRng(ByRef prange As Range)

Set r1 = prange

End Property
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be the code inside the userform

```
Option Explicit
Dim mRng As Range
Public Property Get myRng() As Range
    Set myRng = mRng
End Property

Public Property Set myRng(nRg As Range)
    Set mRng = nRg
End Property
```

Just a simple example

```
Option Explicit

    Sub Test()
    Dim frm As UserForm1
    Dim rg As Range

        Set frm = New UserForm1
        Set frm.myRng = Range("A1")
        Set rg = frm.myRng
        Debug.Print rg.Address

    End Sub
```

Comment: still no change, meanwhile I doubt you can use properties to pass range objects in VBA.

Comment: What do you mean no change. You can use properties to pass a range object.

Comment: I mean I still get the same error, runtime error 91, object variable not set.

Comment: Sorry, but where do you get this error? You did not mention a runtime error before! If you use your global variable prange you are going into the wrong direction.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I thought object required is always a runtime error. Upon compilation everything is fine. I no longer use prange inside the userform. But allow me to ask how then does the range to be dealt with gets from the invoking procedure into the userform? 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try my simple example? It's best you step through it then you will see what is happening by running the code with [Debug/Step into](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/vba_debug2013.php) or pressing F8

Comment: Maybe a more concise site for [Debug/Step into](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)

Comment: Sorry, I did not create a new instance of the userform. I just used the .load and .show commands with the class design code. Your 2nd simple example helped me.
Thanks a lot Storax!

Comment: Then have a look at [this](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) and why it's usually not a good idea to use the default instance.

Comment: As you referred to good practice in showing a userform instance, you can find an example regarding modeless forms at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357708/vba-destroy-a-modeless-userform-instance-properly