# Load a UserForm without re-calculating the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel spreadsheet I use the below VBA codes to get a `UserForm` with a **ComboBox** using the values from `sheet1`:

---

List for **ComboBox1** on spreadsheet:

```
     A     B
1    Q1
2    Q2
3    Q3
4    Q4
```

VBA code to **call** UserForm1 (connected to a button on the spreadsheet):

```
Sub Test()
Call UserForm1.Show(vbModeless)
End Sub
```

VBA code of **UserForm1**:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
ComboBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A1:A4").Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

---

All this works fine so far. However, when the user pushes the button to load the `UserForm1` the entire spreadsheet is re-calculated by Excel which takes a lot of time.

Therefore, I tried to change the code to this:

```
Sub Test()
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Call UserForm1.Show(vbModeless)
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

With this code the `UserForm1` is loaded without re-calculating the spreadsheet. 
 However, since I do not want to keep the spreadsheet in the "manual" re-calculating mode I have to set it back to "automatic" within the VBA code.
However, this causes the same problem of the long loading time. The only difference is that the re-calculation now happens after the `UserForm` is displayed.

Is it possible to load the entire `UserForm` without re-calculating the spreadsheet but keep it in automatic calculation mode?

Comment: [1] Try to **hide** the UserForm (better: new userform instance) instead of *unloading*.
[2] (Handle QueryClose to prevent unwanted object destruction). 
[3] Then you can use **`UserForm_Initiate`** instead of `UserForm_Activate` to load data only once. 
[4] See referring themes (thx @Mathieu-Guindau): 
[Destroy a modeless Userform instance properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357708/vba-destroy-a-modeless-userform-instance-properly) and
[UserForm1.Show?](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)

Comment: Is this all your (userform) code?  I would say there's a writing to a cell somewhere from your Userform. I don't think loading will trigger the calculate-event

Comment: I can confirm what @EvR said - loading a simpe userform does not trigger the calculate event, I have put a `=NOW()` formula and loaded a form, it did not recalculate.

Comment: @EvR: Sorry, you are right. This was a mistake in my question. I am using datas from the spreadsheet for the UserForm. I have edited my question.

Comment: @Michi - don't wanna be the devil's advocate, but reading from a spreadsheet does not trigger the calculate event as well...

Comment: @Vityata: I am checking through my original file and I think - thanks to your comments - I found the reason why the loading is caused. My Excel is linked to a BI tool. The tool inserts data directly into the spreadsheet. If I eliminate the data from the BI tool there is no calculation and the UserForm loads immediately. mmmh, now I need to figure out how I can avoid the BI tool to calculate the data when the user form is loaded ...