# Right to left userforms in excel - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Please Look at the code below and test it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   MsgBox "This window converted Right to Left!", vbMsgBoxRtlReading
End Sub
```

This code convert the message window from right to left. As the close button moves to the left of the window. How do I do this for userforms?
(Hope *T.M., Mathieu Guindon* and ... does not say: "*Your question is amiss. Please read the links ...."*)

Like the picture below (Of course photo is photoshop!):

[image]

Comment: There is a [RightToLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/righttoleft-property-microsoft-forms) property on the form.  I've not used it before though and it seems to be stuck on False for me.

Comment: I knew this feature. I want something like the photo I put. (Of course photo is photoshop!).

Comment: I have a feeling it only works on a system with a right-to-left language installed.

Comment: Hi Rory! If so, why can this feature be customized only in the MsgBox?

Comment: Added a solution via API functions independant from language settings- enjoy it :-) @FirstLast

Comment: Edited LongPtr API declarations for actual 64bit installations and the current Get/SetWindowLongPtr function replacing Get/SetWindowLong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simulate Right To Left display as in `MsgBox`**

It'll be necessary to use some **API** *) functions to get the wanted layout *independant* from language settings using right to left functionality by default.

1. Identify the Userform's **handle** to get access to further API methods
2. *Remove* the Userform's **title bar**
3. Replace it e.g. with a Label control displaying the caption and give it drag functionality to move the UserForm (here: `Label1`).
4. Use another control (here: `Label2`) to simulate the system escape "x".

   *) *API - Application Programming Interface*

**A simple UserForm code example**

All you need is to provide for 2 Label controls where `Label1` replaces the title bar and receives the UserForm's caption and `Label2` simulates the system Escape "x". Furthermore this example uses a `Type` declaration for easy disposal of the UserForm **handle** for several event procedures needing it for further API actions.

**► Note to 2nd edit as of 10/22 2018**

As a window handle is declared as `LongPtr` in Office 2010 or higher and as `Long` in versions before, it was necessary to differentiate between the different versions by conditional compile constants (e.g. `#If VBA7 Then ... #Else ... #End If`; cf. section II. using also the `Win64` constant to identify *actually* installed 64bit Office systems - note that frequently Office is installed as 32bit by default).

```
Option Explicit                 ' declaration head of userform code module

#If VBA7 Then                   ' compile constant for Office 2010 and higher
    Private Type TThis          ' Type declaratation
        frmHandle As LongPtr    ' receives form window handle 64bit to identify this userform
    End Type
#Else                           ' older versions
    Private Type TThis          ' Type declaratation
        frmHandle As Long       ' receives form window handle 32bit to identify this userform
    End Type
#End If
Dim this As TThis               ' this - used by all procedures within this module

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' [1] get Form Handle
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  this.frmHandle = Identify(Me) ' get UserForm handle via API call (Long)
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' [2] remove System Title Bar
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  HideTitleBar (this.frmHandle) ' hide title bar via API call
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
' Purpose: Replaces System Title Bar (after removal via API) and receives dragging functionality
   ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ' [3] allow to move UserForm
   ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     If Button = 1 Then DragForm this.frmHandle
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click()
' Purpose:  Label "x" replaces System Escape (after removal in step [2])and hides UserForm
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' [4] hide UserForm
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Layout()
  Me.RightToLeft = True
' Simulated Escape Icon
  Me.Label2.Caption = " x"
  Me.Label2.BackColor = vbWhite
  Me.Label2.Top = 0
  Me.Label2.Left = 0
  Me.Label2.Width = 18: Me.Label2.Height = 18
' Simulated UserForm Caption
  Me.Label1.Caption = Me.Caption
  Me.Label1.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight    ' <~~ assign right to left property
  Me.Label1.BackColor = vbWhite
  Me.Label1.Top = 0: Me.Label1.Left = Me.Label2.Width: Me.Label1.Height = Me.Label2.Height
  Me.Label1.Width = Me.Width - Me.Label2.Width - 4
End Sub
```

**II. Separate code module for API functions**

**a) Declaration head with constants and special API declarations**

It's necessary to provide for different application versions as the code declarations differ in some arguments (e.g. PtrSafe). 64 bit declarations start as follows: `Private Declare PtrSafe ...`

Take also care of the correct declarations via `#If`, `#Else` and `#End If` allowing version dependant compilation.

The prefix `&H` used in constants stands for hexadecimal values.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = &HA1&
Private Const HTCAPTION = 2&
Private Const GWL_STYLE = (-16)
Private Const WS_BORDER = &H800000
Private Const WS_DLGFRAME = &H400000
Private Const WS_CAPTION = WS_BORDER Or WS_DLGFRAME

#If VBA7 Then                                               ' True if you're using Office 2010 or higher
    ' [0] ReleaseCapture
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub ReleaseCapture Lib "User32" ()
    ' [1] SendMessage
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "User32" _
      Alias "SendMessageA" _
      (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
      ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr    ' << arg's hWnd, wParam + function type: LongPtr
    ' [2] FindWindow
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "User32" _
            Alias "FindWindowA" _
           (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
            ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr        ' << function type: LongPtr
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ' Two API functions requiring the Win64 compile constant for 64bit Office installations
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    #If Win64 Then                                          ' true if Office explicitly installed as 64bit
      ' [3a] Note that GetWindowLong has been replaced by GetWindowLongPtr
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "User32" _
            Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" _
           (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
      ' [3b] Note that GetWindowLong has been replaced by GetWindowLongPtr
      '      Changes an attribute of the specified window.
      '      The function also sets a value at the specified offset in the extra window memory.
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongPtr Lib "User32" _
            Alias "SetWindowLongPtrA" _
           (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal nIndex As Long, _
            ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    #Else                                                   ' true if Office install defaults 32bit
      ' [3aa] Note that GetWindowLong has been replaced by GetWindowLongPtr Alias GetWindowLongA !
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "User32" _
            Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
           (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
      ' [3bb] Note that GetWindowLong has been replaced by GetWindowLongPtr Alias SetWindowLongA !
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongPtr Lib "User32" _
            Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
           (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal nIndex As Long, _
            ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr

    #End If

    ' [4] DrawMenuBar
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DrawMenuBar Lib "User32" _
           (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long                  ' << arg hWnd: LongPtr

#Else                                                       ' True if you're using Office before 2010 ('97)

    Private Declare Sub ReleaseCapture Lib "User32" ()
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "User32" _
          Alias "SendMessageA" _
          (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" _
            Alias "FindWindowA" _
           (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
            ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long


    Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
            Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
           (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
            ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
            Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
           (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
            ByVal nIndex As Long, _
            ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar Lib "User32" _
           (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
#End If
```

**b) Following Procedures (after section a)**

```
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' 3 Procedures using API
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

#If VBA7 Then                               ' Office 2010 and higher
    Public Function Identify(frm As Object) As LongPtr
    ' Purpose: [1] return window handle of form
    ' Note:    vbNullString instead of ThunderXFrame (97) and class names of later versions
      Identify = FindWindow(vbNullString, frm.Caption)
    End Function

    Public Sub HideTitleBar(hWnd As LongPtr)
    ' Purpose: [2] remove Userform title bar
      SetWindowLongPtr hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) And Not WS_CAPTION
    End Sub
        Public Sub ShowTitleBar(hWnd As LongPtr)
        ' Purpose: show Userform title bar
          SetWindowLongPtr hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) Or WS_CAPTION
        End Sub

    Public Sub DragForm(hWnd As LongPtr)
    ' Purpose: [3] allow to drag & move userform via control (here via e.g.: Label1)
      Call ReleaseCapture
      Call SendMessage(hWnd, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0&)
    End Sub

#Else                                       ' vers. before Office 2010 (Office '97)
    Public Function Identify(frm As Object) As Long
    ' Purpose: [1] return window handle of form
    ' Note:    vbNullString instead of ThunderXFrame (97) and class names of later versions
      Identify = FindWindow(vbNullString, frm.Caption)
    End Function
    Public Sub HideTitleBar(hWnd As Long)
    ' Purpose: [2] remove Userform title bar
      SetWindowLong hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) And Not WS_CAPTION
    End Sub
    '    Public Sub ShowTitleBar(HWND As Long)
    '    ' Purpose: show Userform title bar
    '      SetWindowLong HWND, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(HWND, GWL_STYLE) Or WS_CAPTION
    '    End Sub

    Public Sub DragForm(hWnd As Long)
    ' Purpose: [3] allow to drag & move userform via control (here via e.g.: Label1)
      Call ReleaseCapture
      Call SendMessage(hWnd, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0&)
    End Sub


#End If
```

**► Caveat:** *API declarations not tested for **actually** installed 64 bit systems in Office 2010 or higher.* The **2nd Edit as of 10/22 2018** tries to correct several `LongPtr` declarations (only for pointers to a → handle or → memory location) and using the current Get/SetWindowLongPtr function differentiating explicitly between `Win64` and `Win32`; cf. also edited `Type` declaration in the UserForm code module's declaration head).

See also [Compatibility between 32bit and 64bit Versions of Office 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831(office.14).aspx) and [Office 2010 Help Files: Win32API PtrSafe with 64bit Support](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=9970)

**Additional note**

UserForms are Windows and can be identified by their window *handle*. 
The API function used for this purpose is `FindWindow` disposing of two arguments:
1) A string giving the name of the class of the window it needs to find and 2) a string giving the *caption* of the window (UserForm) it needs to find.

Therefore frequently one distinguishes between version '97 (UserForm class name "ThunderXFrame") and later versions ("ThunderDFrame"):

```
 If Val(Application.Version) < 9 Then 
    hWnd = FindWindow("ThunderXFrame", frm.Caption)   ' if used within Form: Me.Caption
 Else   ' later versions
    hWnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", frm.Caption)   ' if used within Form: Me.Caption
 End If
```

However using `vbNullString` (*and* unique captions!) instead makes coding much easier:

```
 hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, frm.Caption)         ' if used within Form: Me.Caption
```

**Recommended further reading**

UserForm code modules actually are **classes** and should be used as such. So I recommend reading M. Guindon's article  [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/). - Possibly of some interest, as well is [Destroy a modeless UserForm instance properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357708/vba-destroy-a-modeless-userform-instance-properly)

Comment: Hello dear T.M.! I really enjoy the class you are teaching and I thank you for that. My system are 64-bit and my Office are 2016. So the code did not work on my system [(Error image).](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bmve7tgkplzaphd/Untitled.jpg?dl=0) However, thank you again for your detailed response. Good luck.

Comment: [Error Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bmve7tgkplzaphd/Untitled.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: See edit - 64bit API declarations start as follows: `Private Declare PtrSafe ...` - @FirstLast

Comment: [Result Picture: Thank you very much T.M.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gka2bai6rp2f3k0/Result%20picture.jpg?dl=0)