# Excel VBA Get value (Integer K) found in "UserForm1" Private Sub script, over to the "Module1" Sub Script

Tags: excel, vba, module, combobox, userform

I have trouble getting my value `K` (Integer) from my `Private Sub` in the `UserForm1` over to my `Sub` in `Module1`.
I Use the `UserForm1` to declare what sheet I want to run code on (by choosing from a dropdown list that pops up, and then declare that as a value/Integer between 2 and 9), so I only need to transfer the value `K` I find in the `UserForm1` `Private Sub` over to the `Sub` in my `Module1`.

I hope that was understandable, i.e. I want to be able to read the value `K` found in the `UserForm1`, in my `Module1` script.

My current code is as follows, Beginning with the `Module` part:

```
Sub HenteMengderFraAutoCAD()
Dim K As Integer

Load UserForm1
UserForm1.Show

MsgBox (K)

Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Next is my code in the `UserForm` where I find the value to use in the code :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
ComboBox1.Clear

With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "M350 og XT"
    .AddItem "STB 300+450"
    .AddItem "Alufix"
    .AddItem "MevaDec og MevaFlex"
    .AddItem "Alshor Plus"
    .AddItem "Rapidshor"
    .AddItem "KLK og Sjaktdragere"
End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If ComboBox1 = "M350 og XT" Then
    K = 2
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "STB 300+450" Then
    K = 3
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "Alufix" Then
    K = 4
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "MevaDec og MevaFlex" Then
    K = 5
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "Alshor Plus" Then
    K = 6
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "Rapidshor" Then
    K = 7
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "KLK og Sjaktdragere" Then
    K = 9
End If
MsgBox (K)
UserForm1.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Actual result would be that `MsgBox(K)` in the `Module1` script would show the same number that `MsgBox(K)` show me in the `UserForm1`. 
Now I get the right value for `K` (2 to 9 depending on what i choose in drop down list) in the `MsgBox in the UserForm1`, but in the `Module1 MsgBox` I only get `0`.

In advance, thanks.

Comment: If `K` is declared `Public`, then the following would work:  `MsgBox UserForm1.K`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, in the userform code, you change the inner references of `UserForm1` to `Me`, i.e.

```
UserForm1.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload UserForm1
```

to

```
Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me
```

and declare a public variable in the userform like:

```
Public K As Integer
```

Then you can use:

```
Sub HenteMengderFraAutoCAD()
Dim K As Integer

With New UserForm1
    .Show
    K = .K
End With

MsgBox (K)
End Sub
```

---

**Complete UserForm Code**

```
Option Explicit
Public K As Integer

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
ComboBox1.Clear

With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "M350 og XT"
    .AddItem "STB 300+450"
    .AddItem "Alufix"
    .AddItem "MevaDec og MevaFlex"
    .AddItem "Alshor Plus"
    .AddItem "Rapidshor"
    .AddItem "KLK og Sjaktdragere"
End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If ComboBox1 = "M350 og XT" Then
    K = 2
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "STB 300+450" Then
    K = 3
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "Alufix" Then
    K = 4
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "MevaDec og MevaFlex" Then
    K = 5
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "Alshor Plus" Then
    K = 6
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "Rapidshor" Then
    K = 7
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "KLK og Sjaktdragere" Then
    K = 9
End If
MsgBox (K)
Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Mistella, this was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

`UserForms` are objects. Recommended and robust approach to read/write values from objects is using Properties. You can create a property and then access it in your module

---

Example Code. Read code comments for details.

User Form:

```
Option Explicit

'/ backing field for the custom property
Private m_MyProperty                As Long

'/ A public variable. Not recommended.
Public lAccessibleVariable          As Long

'/ Define property setters and getters
Public Property Let MyProperty(val As Long)
    m_MyProperty = val
End Property

Public Property Get MyProperty() As Long
 MyProperty = m_MyProperty
End Property

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '/ Do something to the property
    MyProperty = 10
    lAccessibleVariable = 100

    '/ Make sure you just hide the form and not close(destroy it)
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Module

```
Sub test()

    '/ Create an instance of the user form
    Dim frm As New UserForm1
    Dim lValFromUserForm  As Long

    '/ launch the user form
    frm.Show


    '/ Read back the property value
    lValFromUserForm = frm.MyProperty

    '/ do something with the returned value
    MsgBox lValFromUserForm

    '/Just for example, access the public variable.
    MsgBox frm.lAccessibleVariable

    '/ Now that you are done, destroy the user form
    Unload frm


End Sub
```

Comment: FYI Further information regarding modeless Userforms can be found at SO question 
[Destroy a modeless Userform instance properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357708/vba-destroy-a-modeless-userform-instance-properly); c.f. also
 https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-the-perfect-userform-in-vba/ using classes   :-)

Comment: @cyboashu Thank you for the thorough example! Very useful for later development and understanding. **I have one question tho:** Why Isn't it recommended to use Public varibles? 
In my whole code I have other `Sub` that also use the vaiable `K`. Could this be a problem? The variable `K` is defined in each og my `Sub` codes.

@T.M. Thanks for the addional information. I will go through thisto learn more.

Answer (score 1):

My approach agrees wtih Brian M Stafford.

1st:declare K as public variable under your UserForm1 before any subroutines,

```
public K as integer
```

2nd:

```
Sub HenteMengderFraAutoCAD()

Load UserForm1
UserForm1.Show

MsgBox (UserForm1.K)

Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```