# VBA raising events from modeless Userfrom

Tags: vba, events, userform

I'm trying to raise events from a modeless userform. My starting point is [this excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357708/vba-destroy-a-modeless-userform-instance-properly). When I show the form **modeless**, the code raising the event executes, but the event handler never runs (I don't get the expected MsgBox when the Cancel button is clicked.) When I  show the form **modal**, the events are handled as desired, but the form is no longer modeless as desired.

The userform named `FormWithEvents` has an `OKButton` and a `CancelButton`; here's the code behind:

```
Option Explicit

Public Event FormConfirmed()
Public Event FormCancelled(ByRef Cancel As Boolean)

Private Function OnCancel() As Boolean
    Dim cancelCancellation As Boolean
    RaiseEvent FormCancelled(cancelCancellation)
    If Not cancelCancellation Then Me.Hide
    OnCancel = cancelCancellation
End Function

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    OnCancel
End Sub

Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
    RaiseEvent FormConfirmed
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = Not OnCancel
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's the code for the `Presenter` class that shows the form:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents myModelessForm As FormWithEvents

Public Sub Show()
    Set myModelessForm = New FormWithEvents
    ' COMMENT OUT ONE OF THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES TO TOGGLE MODELESS OR MODAL
    myModelessForm.Show vbModeless  ' Modeless, but events don't get handled (no msgbox on clicking cancel button)
    ' myModelessForm.Show vbModal     ' Events get handled, but no longer modal
End Sub

Private Sub myModelessForm_FormCancelled(Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Setting cancel to True will leave the form open
    Cancel = MsgBox("Cancel this operation?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation) = vbNo
    If Not Cancel Then
        ' Modeless form was cancelled and is now hidden
        ' ...
        Set myModelessForm = Nothing
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub myModelessForm_FormConfirmed()
    ' Form was okayed and is now hidden
    Set myModelessForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

And here's the code in the main module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunForm()
    With New Presenter
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Any ideas on where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this instead so you can keep your `Presenter` instance in scope:

```
Dim pres as Presenter

Public Sub RunForm()
    Set pres =  New Presenter
    pres.Show
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `RaiseEvent`. Declare a public instance of the `Presenter` class in the standard module.
Option Explicit

```
Public Preter As New Presenter

Public Sub RunForm()

    With New Presenter
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Convert the event procedure to a sub with public scope.

```
Sub FormCancelled(Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Setting cancel to True will leave the form open
    Cancel = MsgBox("Cancel this operation?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation) = vbNo
    If Not Cancel Then
        ' Modeless form was cancelled and is now hidden
        ' ...
        Set myModelessForm = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

The call the sub within the class.

```
Private Function OnCancel() As Boolean

    Dim cancelCancellation As Boolean

    Preter.FormCancelled cancelCancellation
    If Not cancelCancellation Then Me.Hide

    OnCancel = cancelCancellation
End Function
```

I'm not sure but your code line `Set myModelessForm = Nothing` in the class module bother me. I wonder whether the form should be hidden instead so that the code can continue to the `Show` procedure where the form can then be put to rest.