# vba userform modeless

Tags: vba, userform

I need to write a code where it will be possible to deactivate userform when user clicks outside area of userform or another workbook.

I tried

```
Userform.Show vbModeless
```

but it does not give the result I want, when I am clicking back to userform it is impossible to activate it.

For note, I am using wb open { userform.show 0} and whole dblclicking inside sheet.

I think the inizialization or activate will help me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserForm` is the generic type for all UserForms, but user-created UserForms have a special name, by default `UserForm1`, `Userform2`, and so on. So the statement should probably be `UserForm1.Show vbModeless`, not `UserForm.Show vbModeless`. The actual name of a custom UserForm is the value of the form's Name property.

Comment: Fyi Further very interesting reading emphasizing often overlooked aspects, 
especially that a UserForm *is* a **class** module defining the blueprint of an *object* and how to apply a *Model-View-Presenter* pattern:
 ["UserForm1.Show?"](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) at [Destroy a modeless UserForm properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357708/vba-destroy-a-modeless-userform-instance-properly)

Comment: Thank you for your useful link, gruß from Heidelberg to Austria.  UserForms are difficult to understand because they are reference counted Active-X objects.