# Allowing all classes within a project access to a form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am currently designing a project with a windows form. I am also creating classes that I want to interact with this form. Instead of passing through the form to each object I create, is there a way to allow any class to interact with the form. This is mainly for debugging purposes, I only want access to the textboxes. At the moment I have to do this:

```
Dim x as new MyClass(Me)
```

where the me refers to the form I instantiate MyClass in. This means I need to assign a variable the form in the Sub New of the MyClass (creating a new instance of the form is not helpful).
Within the class I access other classes. If there was a way to interact with my form without the need to constantly pass it forward, it would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38382104/8716187  basically treat your form as a class and build out your methods and handlers.

Comment: I already do treat the form as a class, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Encapsulation and OOP

Answer (score -1):

Create a `Public Module` with a `Public` variable declaration of your `Form` and assign it.

```
Public Module FormInstance
    Public Property MyForm as Form1
End Module

'Somewhere on you Form Startup
    FormInstance.MyForm = me
```

Comment: Ok but how do I access myform in another class?

Comment: Just call it from the module, FormInstance.MyForm

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't working but it was because MyForm wasn't being properly defined. Thanks.

Comment: You’re welcome! Please, accept it as answer if it helped you